# PHP/Wordpress - Can't save to uploads directory without permission 777

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

I have a permission problem with saving attachments to my post with the built in wordpress functions. The below code works fine if I have my permissions set to **777** on the **uploads** folder. But any other permissions such as **755** or **775** gives me the following error:

**Warning**:  file_put_contents(/usr/home/givakt/www/dev-2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rocky.jpg) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in **/usr/home/givakt/www/dev-2013/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/editor/save.php** on line **34**
dev-2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rocky.jpg

My php file is located in a subfolder in my theme, could that be the problem? Or is it something else? I really do not want to rely on **777** because of safety reasons.

---

```
$image_url = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$post_id = $_POST['id'];

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$filename = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folder /usr/home/givakt/www/dev-2013/wp-content/uploads/ owner is "givakt".

At default config web server run from another user - "www-data"

If folder have 0775 right, another user can't write into this folder.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like my FTP software was reporting the wrong permissions but now it works.

Comment: please add code to this answer